# PHP JsonSerializable interface and jsonSerialize with nested objects

Tags: php, arrays, json, serialization

I've got a `ResponseGrid` object and I want to encode it in **Json**. This object has got a `$row` variable inside, which will contain an array of `Document` objects.

I implemented `JsonSerializable` interface and `jsonSerialize()` method in both `ResponseGrid` and `Document`.

What I've got is this:

**ResponseGrid.php:**

```
require_once ROOT_DIR . "/business/models/Document.php";

class ResponseGrid implements JsonSerializable {

    private $sEcho;
    private $iTotalRecords;
    private $iTotalDisplayRecords;
    private $rows; // This will contain an Array of Documents

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return [
            'sEcho' => $this->sEcho,
            'iTotalRecords' => $this->iTotalRecords,
            'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $this->iTotalDisplayRecords,
            'rows' => json_encode($this->rows), //This will cause troubles
        ];
    }
}
```

**Document.php:**

```
class Document implements JsonSerializable {

    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $description;
    private $contentId;

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'contentId' => $this->contentId, 
        ];
    }
}
```

If I do an echo of a `ResponseGrid` object filled with two Documents in the `$row` array, I get this

`echo json_encode($responseGrid);`

```
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":27,"iTotalDisplayRecords":4,"rows":"{\"1\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Greece\",\"description\":\"descGreece\",\"contentId\":2},\"2\":{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Rome\",\"description\":\"descRome\",\"contentId\":3}}"}
```

Why is that? Am I doing it wrong? What are all those backslashes?

Comment: you are json_encoding an object before it is yet again json_encoded you only need to add the rows to the ResponseGrid object, no need to encode it before hand. What you are seeing is the escaped string representing the Document object

Comment: @PatrickEvans You're right: I changed `'rows' => json_encode($this->rows)` in `'rows' => $this->rows` and everything works fine now. Thank you. If you'll write it in an answer I'll accept it :)